# Dealing with N+1 Queries in Yii 2

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

Does anyone know if on Yii's ActiveRecord if there is a feature to help us to prevent N+1 queries?

In the example below we need to get documents from people and show in the view the people's names and their document list. If I do using $model->findAll([...]); something like the code below:

```
<?php foreach( $people as $person ): ?>
  <li><?= $person->name</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach( $person->documents as $document ): ?>
        <li><?= $document->number; ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </li>
<?php endfoeach; ?>
```

The Yii will query the database a lot of times.
In Ruby on Rails's ActiveRecord they have an include method where we can use something like: People.includes('documents').

In this way the ActiveRecord makes queries less heavy to get both objects.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ActiveQuery::with()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#with()-detail) method to register eager loading rules.

```
$people = Person::find()->with('documents')->all();
```

This will create 2 queries - first for loading all persons, second for loading all documents related to these persons.

This is quite well explained in Active Record documentation in [Lazy Loading and Eager Loading](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#lazy-eager-loading) section.